# resolve vs reject in promise algorithms

Tags: promise

In a common promise pattern `resolve` represents a success, while `reject` represents a failure.

But in a promise-based algorithm that produces a boolean result the concept of `success`/`failure` is not applicable, and thus no clear decision which result is to be resolved or rejected.

Even when the result isn't boolean, it may be not clearly distinguished as suitable for resolve or reject.

Is there any official recommendation as to choosing resolve vs reject pattern in such cases? Preferably with and without knowing which type of results will be in greater numbers than the other.

Comment: What type of promises are you talking about? A+?

Comment: @MinusFour, Is there a type of promises that's not based or resolve/reject operations? If not, then it is not applicable to the question.

Comment: It's applicable because not all promises implementations leave such ambiguity with boolean results. A+ spec defines independent controls for resolution and rejection and as such you could never have said ambiguity (as you call what you need).

Answer (score 1):

A reject means an exception/error has occurred. There are language errors such as dereferencing a null pointer, and application errors such as a bad HTTP request. How you define what is an exception and what isn't is, is entirely up to you. A `false` value could be very much `resolve`d as it is a perfectly fine value, or it can be deemed as a bad value by your application (say, it logically should never be false, hence it is an exception) and you could then `reject` it instead.

Comment: There are no errors or exceptions in algorithms that I mentioned, there are only different processing paths.

Comment: If it is not an error/exception, then `resolve` the value and use a control statement/expression to figure out which path to take next based on the boolean value.

Comment: That implies the entire algorithm will have no `reject` in it ever, only `resolve`. I'm not sure that's gonna take care of it. The logical paths may suggest otherwise. It's then a matter of how to organize it.

Comment: Why are you using promises for your algorithm in the first place? Are you doing some sort of asynchronous operation such as making network calls or accessing the file system?

Comment: Asynchronous calculation that involves: reading additional data from files, synchronizing calculation across NodeJS processes.

Comment: So that means your algorithm is subject to bad input, file system errors and inter process communication errors. Reject is the means to handle those errors in order to propagate them down the promise chain. If you're using reject to handle both exceptions and control flow, then you're going to have a difficult time trying to discern between the two.

Comment: My question was about asynchronous calculation, primarily, without those additional considerations.

Comment: Right, and like I mentioned, the best practice is to use reject to handle errors, and control statements to handle control flow.

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering if there was a common recommendation related to this. For example, one based on performance, or other high-level considerations :)

Answer (score 0):

There is an important difference between reject and resolve when it comes to successively chained promises as in:

```
a().then(b).then(c).catch(d);
```

In this case, it makes a very big difference whether `a()` resolves or rejects because if it rejects, then `b` and `c` are not called.

So, for purposes of the ability to chain, a successful outcome should resolve with whatever value you want to return and you would not use reject just to signal a `false` value because that ruins the ability to normally chain other async operations.

Reject should signal an error from which successively chained operations should not continue (unless you specifically handle the error case and code it to continue).

Answer (score -1):

There's a difference between a boolean false and an exception.

Comment: I don't even know what to make of such answer.